# Integration googleDrive in ios application

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I use DropBox and SkyDrive in my applications and they work like a charme with a very good documentation, but GoogleDrive is really hard to integrate (to be polite :) ).

I'm not talking about coding but integration in xcode.
i follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios).
In [step 3](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios#step_3_create_and_configure_an_xcode_project) i have 8 point to do, the problem is in point n°7, there's no `Sources` path, i search in the svn folder i download and it's not there. and of course without linking headers i have this issue "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h no such file or directory"(i think that compiler stop there but there's more error).

what can i do ?

Comment: @Ali Afshar, you work at google in googleDrive can you see with ios team for that please :) .

Comment: @Ali Afshar... please look the google drive api integration with ios. Dropbox and Skydrive have done good job but it is very tough to use google drive...

Comment: @RedMak I am facing the same issue.Are you able to resolved it by adding the headerpath.I did add the headerpath but still it give me the same error

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really old, but I had this problem and found a solution.

When you add the "User Header Search Paths" to the source directory, you need to make sure you set it to recursive so it gets all of the contents of that directory. Hope that helps.

Comment: I had add "User Header Search Paths" but still it give me same error.

Answer (score 0):

The [Source](http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Source) directory is immediately under the [trunk](http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) that you checked out.

There is a [Google Developer video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=owlifMbV47k) (embedded at the bottom of the tutorial) that shows all the steps listed in the tutorial. Unfortunately the presenter does skip some troubleshooting and the steps he's following are very slightly different to the current version of the tutorial, but it is still helpful.